# Where is set_text to set an entry text in Python-GTK3?

Tags: python, python-2.7, combobox, gtk, gtk3

In previous pyGTK you could use combobox.set_title(text) to set the text entered into a combobox. Now in Python-GTK3 it doesn't seem to work and the [example](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/combobox.html) does not include setting it. Is there a new method to setting the selection in this case?

Comment: In the title you said `set_text` and the question body you changed that to `set_title`. Which function are you asking about, and what exactly does that function do? I've never heard of a `set_title` function for GtkEntries.

Comment: According to [the docs](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkComboBox.html#gtk-combo-box-set-title) the `set_title` function is deprecated (with no alternative).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Rawing commented, the question is a little bit confused but the goal seems to be: set the text on a Gtk.ComboBox with entry.

pyGTK and Gtk+ 2 have the `set_title` method. [Gtk+ 3 also had](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/ComboBox.html#Gtk.ComboBox.set_title) up to version 3.10 but as commented, it has been deprecated. Anyway the method did the same on both versions, and that was: "***Sets the menu's title in tearoff mode***", which has nothing to do with the entry.

The indicated [example](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/combobox.html) uses a Gtk.ComboxBox with model. To set the content of the entry we can set the active item from the model and the Gtk.Entry will reflect that by showing the text from that same item.

If you add `name_combo.set_active (1)` to the [example](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/combobox.html) code, like this:

```
...
name_combo = Gtk.ComboBox.new_with_model_and_entry(name_store)
name_combo.connect("changed", self.on_name_combo_changed)
name_combo.set_entry_text_column(1) 
name_combo.set_active (1) # ADD THIS LINE <--------------------
vbox.pack_start(name_combo, False, False, 0)
....
```

You will verify that the Gtk.Entry from the Gtk.ComboBox will be filled with text from the model.

If somehow you want to deal directly with the Gtk.Entry you can use Gtk.ComboBox inherited `get_child` method (from Gtk.Bin). Then you can use Gtk.Entry `set_text` method, eg:

```
name_combo = Gtk.ComboBox.new_with_model_and_entry(name_store)
name_combo.connect("changed", self.on_name_combo_changed)
name_combo.set_entry_text_column(1)
name_combo.get_child ().set_text ("Hello World") # <-------------- HERE
vbox.pack_start(name_combo, False, False, 0)
```

If you change the example as shown above, when you run it the Gtk.Entry will show the text as set.

The text will not be in the model though.

Comment: What is "tearoff mode"? You should write the documentation for the GTK3+/Python :)

Comment: @NoBugs Tearoff menu is kind of a legacy mode where you could detach some ui items and they would have their own window. The set title method was used to set the title of the window when in that mode. Check the deprecated [tearoff menu item](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTearoffMenuItem.html) description. That ux interaction has been slowly discontinued and deprecated. :)  Thanks and Good luck